# How to upload multiple images in CakePHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am able to upload a single image in CakePHP but I want upload multiple images at once. How can I achieve it?

My Controller page is like this:

```
 public function display() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->data['Image']) {
                $image = $this->data['Image']['image'];
                //allowed image types
                $imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
                //upload folder - make sure to create one in webroot
                $uploadFolder = "upload";
                //full path to upload folder
                $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;


                //check if image type fits one of allowed types
                foreach ($imageTypes as $type) {
                    if ($type == $image['type']) {
                      //check if there wasn't errors uploading file on serwer
                        if ($image['error'] == 0) {
                             //image file name
                            $imageName = $image['name'];
                            //check if file exists in upload folder
                            if (file_exists($uploadPath . '/' . $imageName)) {
                                            //create full filename with timestamp
                                $imageName = date('His') . $imageName;
                            }
                            //create full path with image name
                            $full_image_path = $uploadPath . '/' . $imageName;
                            //upload image to upload folder
                            if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $full_image_path)) {
                                $this->Session->setFlash('File saved successfully');
                                $this->set('imageName',$imageName);
                            } else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash('There was a problem uploading file. Please try again.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash('Error uploading file.');
                        }
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Unacceptable file type');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->render('home');
    }
```

My view page is like this

```
<?php
/* display message saved in session if any */
echo $this->Session->flash();
?>
<div> 
<div class="images-form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Image', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Image'); ?></legend>
        <?php

        echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>

</div>
<div class="image-display">
<?php 

//if is set imageName show uploaded picture

if(isset($imageName)) {
echo $this->Html->image('/upload/'.$imageName, array('alt' => 'uploaded image'));
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by adding 2 or more input fields in your form like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo $this->Form->input('image.', array('type' => 'file')); //note the . at the end of the name.
}
```

This way the name of the file will be: data[Image][image][] and if you print the data in your controller, you will see the array of images.

The other way is by using ajax upload library such as: fineuploader.com

Comment: I am using this, but it just throws an error. What should the .dot do?